# Keyboard shortcuts for select file menu in Macos

Tags: macos

There's that "select file" dialog in OSX which I happen to use all the time. I've been wondering if there are some shortcuts that could help navigate the dialog. I'm looking for anything that can make working with that dialog easier, mainly for things like "jump to a specific path", "quick search", etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Pressing ~, /, or ⇧⌘G opens a go to folder sheet
- ⌘⌫ selects the buttons for not saving a document
- ⇧⌘. shows or hides invisible files
- ⌘F focuses the search field
- ⌘D goes to the desktop, ⇧⌘O to documents, and ⌥⌘L to downloads
- ⌘. closes the dialogs even if the search field has focus